# Comment nommer le « Canadian Cross » (informatique) ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, terminologie, informatique

En informatique on trouve le [*Canadian Cross*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler#Canadian_Cross), soit « a technique for building cross compilers for other machines » (Wikipedia), mot à mot donc une technique pour « compiler des compilateurs [croisés](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilateur#Compilation_crois%C3%A9e) pour d'autres architectures cibles » ou pour mettre au point des chaînes de compilation capables d'accomplir cette tâche. On explique la référence au Canada vu la présence de trois partis politiques nationaux au moment où on choisit de dire ça (la technique implique jusqu'à quatre compilateurs). Ce n'est pas parfaitement clair, je ne peux pas dire pourquoi en langue anglaise on décide d'employer *cross* ou de réduire si c'est le cas *cross-compiler* à *cross* dans cette composition ; j'aime même trouvé un intitulé avec le pluriel ([*Canadian Crosses*](https://web.archive.org/web/20041009155533/http://www.objsw.com/CrossGCC/FAQ-4.html#sec:CanadianCross)), qui me laisse encore plus perplexe. Je dois donc me débrouiller avec le seul vocabulaire etc. de l'informatique en langue française.

Dans des traductions (parfois automatiques) j'ai trouvé « croix canadienne » ou « compilation croisée canadienne ». Je me suis demandé pourquoi on n'avait pas « [à la](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_la) canadienne » sans *croisée* par exemple ou « croisé canadien » sans *compilation*.

---

Hormis l'emploi du terme en anglais, quelle combinaison de termes trouve-t-on la plus juste et pourquoi ?

Comment: Un tripartilateur ? ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pour commencer, si on voulait une expression qui soit intrinsèquement logique et pas un calque de l'anglais, on ne traduirait pas « *cross-compiler* » par « compilateur croisé ». Le « *cross* » de « *cross-compiler* » n'est pas lié à la forme d'une croix, mais au fait qu'on traverse une barrière d'architecture. On pourrait donc parler de « compilateur transverse » ou de « compilateur traversant » ou d'« hétérocompilateur ». Une « *Canadian cross-compilation* » serait alors quelque chose comme une « chaîne de compilations transverses » ou une « compilation multitraversante » ou une « polyhétérocompilation » (ou peut-être y a-t-il une racine grecque plus adaptée ?).

Mais si l'on veut être compris, un « *cross-compiler* » est un « compilateur croisé ». On peut alors choisir de garder l'adjectif « Canadien » pour traduire « *Canadian cross-compilation* » : après tout, cet adjectif est arbitraire et n'est pas lié au sens de l'expression. C'est donc une « compilation croisée Canadienne » ou un « compilation croisée à la Canadienne ».

Vu que l'expression « *Canadian cross-compilation* » n'est pas très usité en anglais, et qu'il faut donc de toute façon préciser le sens lorsqu'on s'en sert, on peut aussi la traduire de manière moins obscure. On peut tout simplement parler de « compilation croisée multiple », ce qui a un sens assez transparent.

Comment: Merci ! Ouais pour le _cross_ le GDT a [_transcompilateur_](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8370326), dans la direction que tu empruntais. Je comprends qu'on traverse et donc pour moi le cross du terme est une réduction du _cross-compiler_. Mais la croix du christianisme a 3 branches hors de terre et ça commençait à me déranger ces coïncidences. En plus le _crosses_ au pluriel, là je décide de le voir comme des passages justement comme je ne sais pas ce qui en anglais aurait motivé quelqu'un à mettre ça au pluriel dans un titre, et que ce n'est pas le sujet non plus.